# pycharm: keyboard shortcut to switch between windows

Tags: pycharm

I'm starting to use PyCharm on Mac and it's been nice (I'm a looong time vim user BTW). One thing I'm missing is the ability to switching between tabs. I have to reach the touch pad and click on tab bar. Is there a keyboard shortcut for this?

Comment: What do you mean by code Windows? Do you mean tabs within the IDE? If yes then see this https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/navigating-between-editor-tabs.html.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Ctrl-[Left, Right] or Ctrl-Alt-[Left, Right] didn't work. But Ctrl-Tab did.

Answer (score 2):

right tab: cmd + shift + [

left tab: cmd + shift + ]

You can change this in Pycharm/Preferences/Keymap/Select Next Tab